# Munin: some pluggins stopped working after moving to different *virtual* host

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, munin

I used munin as monitoring serfice and I was happy with it. It is located on localhost machine with `CNAME` being `server.domain.com`. Trying to access `server.domain.com` from remote machine showed up munin main page with graphs and such cool stuff. After some time, graphs for certain pluggins stoppen working, but I **did not** noticed that. After few days, I realized, that something is wrong with my munin and I was thinking, how is it possible, that munin stopped working properly, even if I made no changes to it. I realized, that the only configuration, that **could** affect munin's performace was changes to apache configuration (basically I made up bunch of VirtualHosts to manage my subdomains).

I think, that munin thinks, that it is located on different machine than `localhost` (for example because mysql says `Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'` and I have no idea who the user is and where does it know such user (it is nowehere to be found in munin's configuration files) and it worked before and I did no changes to munin configuration **at all**).

So, to recap, munin was working fine. After changes to apache2 VirtualHost configuration (and possibly moving munin around, but still on single machine), graphs for mysql, apache, NFS stopped working. Other graphs (like disk, network, processes) are still working correctly.

I am able to provide any other information about the system or logs from apache, munin, mysql or whatever, but I do not know which logs to provide since I am not aware what is the main cause of the problem.

#### Edit

I am providing munin logs.
`munin-update.log:`

```
2015/09/11 16:20:02 [INFO]: Starting munin-update
2015/09/11 16:20:02 [INFO] starting work in 9389 for server.domain.com/127.0.0.1:4949.
2015/09/11 16:20:04 [WARNING] Service nfs_client on server.domain.com/127.0.0.1:4949 returned no data for label link
/* same message for label: lookup,setattr,readlink,create,remove,write,read,symlink,rename,rmdir,commit,mknod,fsstat,getattr,fsinfo,pathconf,readdirplus,mkdir,access,readdir */

2015/09/11 16:20:04 [WARNING] Service nfsd on server.domain.com/127.0.0.1:4949 returned no data for label access
/* same message for label: mkdir,readdir,fsinfo,pathconf,readdirplus,fsstat,getattr,commit,mknod,symlink,rename,rmdir,remove,write,read,create,link,lookup,setattr,readlink */

2015/09/11 16:20:08 [WARNING] Service mysql_innodb on server.domain.com/127.0.0.1:4949 returned no data for label free
/* same message for label: open_downgrade,readlink,server_caps,setclientid_confirm,setclientid,getacl,lock,write,rename,open_noattr,statfs,close,lookup_root,getattr,delegreturn,fsinfo,access,lookup,link,setattr,locku,create,renew,lockt,read,remove,symlink,setacl,commit,open_confirm,pathconf,openreaddir */

2015/09/11 16:20:10 [WARNING] Service mysql_queries on server.domain.com/127.0.0.1:4949 returned no data for label select
/* same message for label: update,insert,delete,replace,cache_hits */

2015/09/11 16:20:10 [INFO]: Munin-update finished for node domain.com;server.domain.com (8.45 sec)
2015/09/11 16:20:10 [INFO] Reaping Munin::Master::UpdateWorker<domain.com;server.domain.com>.  Exit value/signal: 0/0
2015/09/11 16:20:10 [INFO]: Munin-update finished (8.69 sec)
```

`munin-node.log:`

```
2015/09/11-16:20:02 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53822" Local: "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4949"
2015/09/11-16:20:02 [9390] Error output from mysql_:
2015/09/11-16:20:02 [9390]      Unknown graph  at /etc/munin/plugins/mysql_ line 831.
2015/09/11-16:20:02 [9390] Service 'mysql_' exited with status 255/0.
2015/09/11-16:20:02 [9390] Error output from mysql_:
2015/09/11-16:20:02 [9390]      Unknown graph  at /etc/munin/plugins/mysql_ line 874.
2015/09/11-16:20:02 [9390] Service 'mysql_' exited with status 255/0.
2015/09/11-16:20:05 [9390] Error output from mysql_isam_space_:
2015/09/11-16:20:05 [9390]      /usr/bin/mysqlshow: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2015/09/11-16:20:05 [9390] Service 'mysql_isam_space_' exited with status 1/0.
2015/09/11-16:20:05 [9390] Error output from mysql_isam_space_:
2015/09/11-16:20:05 [9390]      /usr/bin/mysqlshow: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2015/09/11-16:20:05 [9390] Service 'mysql_isam_space_' exited with status 1/0.
2015/09/11-16:20:08 [9390] Error output from mysql_innodb:
2015/09/11-16:20:08 [9390]      ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2015/09/11-16:20:08 [9390]      ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2015/09/11-16:20:10 [9390] Error output from mysql_queries:
2015/09/11-16:20:10 [9390]      mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
2015/09/11-16:20:10 [9390]      error: 'Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Comment: Debian-sys-maint is a mysql user that is used for restarting, stopping, starting the mysql daemon. You're only missing the stats for MySQL, or has it completely stopped working? What do munin logs say?

Comment: @Vladimir I am missing munin stats (graphs) for `mysql`, `nfs`, `apache`

Comment: @Vladimir and I added logs to question.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this can help you? https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/ispconfig-munin-and-mysql.19085/

Comment: Nope, as I said, everything was working properly until I did that apache configuration. In my opinion, munin thinks that he is running remotely and uses different methods to get data.